# How to put condition into the XPATH while extracting XML using Pentaho?

Tags: xml, xpath, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

```
                  <table>
                    <tr styleCode="normRow xMergeUp">
                       <td ID="problem30comment" colspan="2" styleCode="allIndent">
                          <paragraph styleCode="cellHeader">Overview:</paragraph>
                          <paragraph>Test</paragraph>
                       </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ID="problem29" styleCode="altRow">
                       <td ID="problem29name">Anemia</td>
                       <td>07/30/2015</td>
                    </tr>
                 </table>
```

I have above XML tags. So I want to check the  tag contains the `<paragraph>` tag or not. If yes then get `<paragraph>` tag value or direct take `<td>` value.

I am using "Get data from XML" in Pentaho.

Comment: "check the tag contains the tag or not" : I guess one word is missing.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please use the preview window before posting - several of your XML tags were missing in your text, because they were not `inline formatted`.